# Finding the corresponding noun given an adjective

Tags: nouns, dutch

I am developing a Question and Answer system in the Dutch language. In order to get an answer from the system I send a query to DBPedia which either returns me answer or does not. Sentences like: "What is the X from Y" are perfectly accepted since I can query for example "height" immediately from the DBPedia page in the sentence "What is the length of Roger Federer". However if I want to query the system with the question: "How tall is Roger Federer", the system is not able to convert the word "tall" to "height. One should note that properties like "length" or "height" are directly found on DBPedia, but words like "tall" are not.

Is there any way to generate such pairs, or does someone already have such a file? I don't mind if the file is in English. Any ideas are appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: Interesting question.  There may be a generalisable data-driven approach, but my guess is that you're best off making templates.  Are you fine with scraping Google infoboxes?